# Two simultanious edit texts on android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am creating a unit converter for android. It has two edit texts and i want to update one as the user types in the numbers in the other but i can't get it.

I have tried several methods but so far i can't get this to work. I am very new to android and i have already made this app in java but here i just can't seem to get it.

So far i got the thing to work with the on click method but i would very much like it to show the conversion as the user inputs the numbers in the edit text

Comment: Post your code what you have tried.

Comment: Use TextWatcher http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html

Comment: The solution posted by Assa worked! thank you guys

Comment: I'm very new to this page and don't know how to post code. sorry :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a **TextChangedListener** as Chadi suggested, but I suggest to implement in a different mode. Take a look at the following implementation of **[`TextWatcher`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html)**

```
        EditText firstEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstEdit);

        firstEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
               //Do here your conversion
               secondEdit.setText(convertedText);
            }
        });
```

I suggest you using [**afterTextChanged**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html#onTextChanged(java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int,%20int)) because as the official doc states it is there where you are sure that the text is actually already changed.

Official Doc:

> This method is called to notify you that, somewhere within s, **the text**
>   **has been changed**. It is legitimate to make further changes to s from
>   this callback, **but be careful not to get yourself into an infinite
>   loop, because any changes you make will cause this method to be called
>   again recursively**. (You are not told where the change took place
>   because other afterTextChanged() methods may already have made other
>   changes and invalidated the offsets. But if you need to know here, you
>   can use setSpan(Object, int, int, int) in onTextChanged(CharSequence,
>   int, int, int) to mark your place and then look up from here where the
>   span ended up.

Comment: Thanks Assa, i had tried using the textWatcher but the way i implemented it gave me an infinite loop resulting in a stack overflow error. But i see how to properly use the textWatcher now! thank you!

Comment: @DanielBernal Pleasure is mine :)!

Answer (score 1):

Do that with the `addTextChangedListener` like this:

```
yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            //do your conversion
            yourSecondEditText.setText(text);

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Comment: This is the answer, but as Assa states; we should use the afterTextChanged because that way we ensure that the text has been changed. Thank you!